# How to skip first in map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to skip the first in the `.map` function what I do now is this:

```
block.gallery.map((item, i) => (
       <div className="gallery-item" key={i}>
        { block.gallery.length > 4 && i !== 0 ?
          <div className="inner">
             <img src={block.gallery[i].images.thumbnail_sm} alt={block.title} srcSet={`${block.gallery[i].images.thumbnail_md} 1x, ${block.gallery[i].images.thumbnail_lg} 2x`} className="img-fluid" title="" />
             <div className="img-overlay">
               <span className="img-overlay-body">{ block.gallery.length - 4 }+ <span className="hidden-xs">Foto's</span></span>
             </div>
           </div>
           :
           <img src="http://placehold.it/800x538" alt="" className="img-fluid" title="" />
          }
```

Comment: Why you are using `map` here as you are not returning anything. To loop the array you can use `forEach` and to skip the first item you can check `if (i > 0)`

Comment: @Aruna the thing being returned is the `<div className="gallery-item">` and everything it contains.

Comment: It would help to update your question given that your code no longer uses `.map`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

So [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) it to skip the first

```
block.gallery.slice(1).map(...)
```

You also need to reference the item passed into map, not using the index with the orginal array.

```
block.gallery[i].images.thumbnail_sm
```

should be

```
item.images.thumbnail_sm
```

Comment: Why would it show the first picture when you skip the first index with slice? You also would need to get rid of the i==0 check inside.

Comment: You still get the first one because you are not referencing the array in the map

Comment: And now every item in `.map` function get the span with x+ photos but how do I set this to only the last one? maybe you also could help me out on that one

Comment: Check to see if it is the last one? `((item, i, arr)=>` and `if(arr.length-1===i)`

Comment: around the span element?

Answer (score 3):

You can also remove the first element, and retrieve it at any point, using [`Array.prototype.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift); however, *this modifies the original array.*

```
const head = block.gallery.shift(); // removes and stores first element in "head"

console.log(block.gallery) // array with first element removed
```

Comment: This is the way to do it if you want to keep track of what was removed and not create a new array.