# How to not show the first item on a array in a map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I receive an array like this from backend:

```
[
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "John",
    language: "Enlgish" 
  },
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "Chris",
    language: "Spanish" 
  },
    {
    id: 2,
    name: "Bastian",
    language: "German" 
  }
]
```

So I display the languages from this array in a table, and to do that I map through them.
I don't want to show the first language on the first object of this array

Parent.js

```
const [language, setLanguage] = useState ([])

useEffect(() => {
 axios
    .get('api').then((res) => {setLanguage(response.data.languages)})
}, [])
```

Child.js

```
return(
       {language.map((lang, i) => {
           return (
               <tr key={"item-" + i}>
                  <td>
                    <div>
                       <input
                          type="text"
                          value={
                            lang.language
                              ? lang.language.shift()
                              : lang.language
                          }
                      </div>                 
                    </td>
                </tr>
          ))}
)
```

So what I have tried by far is the shift method which removes the first item of an array, but it didn't work.
This error happened :`TypeError: lang.language.shift is not a function`

How can I fix this?

Comment: why not use i in your code? if i is 0 skip it.

Comment: Use `language.slice(1).map(...)`. PS given that `language` holds an array, it should probably be plural in name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to skip first in map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679613/how-to-skip-first-in-map-function)

Comment: `setLanguage(response.data.languages.slice(0,1))`

Answer (score -1):

Use the index

```
   {language.map((lang, i) => {
    (i > 0) && (
       return (
        ......
```

Comment: Tried this way, but it showed me a syntax error about the ```return```. Is a other way to display it