# How to push all ids to an array except first id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, api

How to push all response' ids except first id ? I mean below code pushes all ids to **idList** array. I want to push all ids again but except first id should not be pushed.How to edit below code ?

```
const getAllId = async () => {
  let res = await axios({
    method: "get",
    url: "/v1/feed",
  });
  const idList = [];
  res.feed.forEach((item) => {
    idList.push(item.id);
  });
  return idList;
};
```

Comment: er... use a counter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to skip first in map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679613/how-to-skip-first-in-map-function)

Comment: combined with [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.map` to transform an array to an array](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [`.slice()`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to skip the first item in `res.feed`.

```
const res = await axios({
  method: "get",
  url: "/v1/feed",
});
return res.feed.slice(1).map(item => item.id);
```

If you really want to use `forEach` and not slice the feed, [use the `index` parameter it passes to the callback](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#parameters):

```
const idList = [];
res.feed.forEach((item, index) => {
  if(index > 0) idList.push(item.id);
});
return idList;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This One Example**

```
const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const newIds = ids.slice(1); // get a copy of the array from the second element to the end
console.log(newIds); // Output: [2, 3, 4, 5]
```